# Azure application gateway unhealthy threshold

Tags: azure, threshold, azure-application-gateway

What does the unhealthy threshold in the Azure Application Gateway configuration represent

Comment: Please allow edit to this question. Add metric you are looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a **[health Probe property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-probe-overview#default-health-probe-settings)** which called a `Probe retry count`. The back-end server is marked down after the consecutive probe failure count reaches the unhealthy threshold.

For more details about **Application Gateway health monitoring**, refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-probe-overview).

Answer (score 0):

Application gateway probes the backend server every 30 seconds(Default value). Lets say your threshold value is set to 3.

If the first probe request fails, Application gateway will not wait for 30 seconds,but will send 2 consecutive probes to check if the backend is responding. If not , Application gateway will mark the server as unhealthy and as soon as the server responds back to the probe, it will mark the server healthy again.

Comment: As soon? Currently I have an *"unhealty"* backend pool, it has been resolved it's issue, the health probe shows in green when tested but the app gateway still has it marked as unhealty for the last 15mins